# Prevent Gitlab CI Runners from running tasks unless tagged

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Gitlab jobs and runners can be tagged - so only runners with the tag can run the job. See documentation here: http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#tags

I want to ensure that my runners that have tags *only* pick up tagged jobs. Currently jobs without any tags are eligible to run on these runners too.

Can this be done?

Comment: Can you tell us your use case or need for such scenario? There might be a different approach to your problem.

Comment: I've just setup some runners that are capable of building docker images. However these runners are not capable of doing any regular java etc builds. Adding the new builders causes existing jobs to break.

I could go and tag all the existing builders and jobs, but I was hoping to avoid this.

Comment: You could use project specific runners if we are talking about distinct projects. But if one projects needs a java and a docker capable runner I see no way around tagging the old runners. I guess, editing the `.gitlab-ci.yml` files of all the projects it the biggest issue here?

Comment: Do your `.gitlab-ci.yml` use docker images? If yes, do they use the same docker image or not? If they are different, you can use the `allowed_images` setting to differentiate them. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#the-runnersdocker-section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- During the Registration process of the runner: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html

> 6. Choose whether the Runner should pick up jobs that do not have tags, you can change this later in GitLab's UI (defaults to false):

- In the Admin panel `https://<SERVER>/admin/runners`
- And in the config dialog of your specific runner (URL: `https://<PROJECT_URL>/settings/ci_cd`)

...you can set the option, to only run tagged jobs.

If you then also [tag your jobs accordingly](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#tags), you have reached your goal.

e.g.:

```
job:
  tags:
    - ruby
    - postgres
```